# Replace values in a specificities key with a string

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, command-line

I have a text file in which some lines are in the form:

```
some text key1="value1" key2="value2",text_to_copy_1 
some text
some text key1="value3" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text
...
```

And I wish to replace the values in key1 with the text_to_copy_X.
So, I can get something like:

```
some text key1="text_to_copy_1" key2="value2",text_to_copy_1 
some text
some text key1="text_to_copy_2" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text
...
```

How can I process this file in bash (preferable) or python? 
INFO: text_to_copy_X ends with a final white space that I do not want to consider. Thanks

Comment: Where does text_to_copy **end** - always at the end of line?

Comment: wrt `that I do not want to consider` - that's never an option, you have to consider whether to include it as part of the replacement text or not. I assume you mean `that I do not want to be part of the text that I copy into key1="..."`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'"' '$2!="" {print $1 "\042" substr($5,2) "\042" $3 "\042" $4 "\042" $5}
           $2=="" {print}' <(sed 's| *$||' input)
```

Firstly `sed` removes all trailing spaces from your `input` file, as you do not want to consider them.

Then awk proceeds with that result, using `"` as delimiter.

Comment: I saw that I have some line with 3 keys and other with 2 and that sed command with 3 key doesn't work. it is possibile to update it to have a variable number of keys? For instance a line is: some text key1="value1" key2="text_to_copy_2" key3="value4",text_to_copy_2

Comment: @Giacota You should open a new question for that. Also, see what to do when someone answers your question <https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers>.

Comment: Understood. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

With a sed that has a `-E` flag to use EREs (e.g. GNU sed or OSX/BSD sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/(key1=")[^"]*(".*,(.*[^[:space:]]))/\1\3\2/' file
some text key1="text_to_copy_1" key2="value2",text_to_copy_1
some text
some text key1="text_to_copy_2" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text
```

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this with `sed`

```
➜  ~  cat text
some text
some text key1="value3" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text key1="value3" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text key1="value3" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text key1="value3" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text
```

```
$>   sed  -E "s/key1=\"[^ ]+\"(.+),(.+)((\ )$)?/key=\"\2\"\1,\2/" text
some text
some text key="text_to_copy_2" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text key="text_to_copy_23" key2="value4",text_to_copy_23
some text key="text_to_copy_4" key2="value4",text_to_copy_4
some text key="text_to_copy_2" key2="value4",text_to_copy_2
some text
```

Comment: almost done, only a minor thing because some "text_to_copy_X " (not all) have an ending white space that I do not want to copy. inside the key value. How can I avoid this? At the moment the result is similar to: some text key="text_to_copy_2 " key2="value4",text_to_copy_2

Comment: Updated the regex to exclude the white space

Comment: Small issue that I just noticed. Some "text_to copy_X " have a white space inside and with your last modification this only the first part is taken. For instance, I get "text_to" and not "text_to copy_X". Can you update the regex to support this? Thanks

Comment: Updated the regex